# C4267 conversion warning in constructor - can't fix with overload?

Tags: c++

The following code produces compiler warning C4267:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int size) {...};
MyClass(someVector.size()); //C4267 - Conversion of size_t to int
```

As std::vector::size() returns a size_t. One way to fix this would be use of a cast when invoking the constructor, but this would require using the cast every time MyClass is used.
Instead, I would like to create an overload of MyClass' constructor which accepts a size_t, performs the cast, and then proceeds as normal:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int size) {...};
MyClass::MyClass(size_t size) {...};
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting the C4267 compiler warning despite doing this. To make matters worse, other invocations of MyClass occurring elsewhere (which pass an int) now generate compiler error C2668, "'function' : ambiguous call to overloaded function".

I'd really like to be able to solve this without having to modify warning levels.

Comment: Why not get rid of the `int` constructor?

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you using?  It works with VS 2017.

Comment: Or do you define `size_t` as a type within `MyClass`?

Comment: @Jonathan Great idea, that solves it.

Comment: `std::vector<>::size()` returns `std::vector<>::size_type`. While it is more than likely to be `std::size_t`, it still might be a better idea to use `std::vector<>::size_type`.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by getting rid of the int constructor altogether and just using a size_t constructor.

A plain int uses 32 bits, while a size_t uses 64 bits. Converting from a size_t to an int risks loss of data, but converting the other way around poses no such danger. As a result, existing int uses of the constructor do not yield a conversion warning when converting to size_t.

Many thanks @Jonathan Potter.

Comment: Um... `std::size_t` is an *unsigned* type, while `int` is a *signed* type. Which means that conversion from `int` to `std::size_t` might easily result in a loss of value. The loss is probably reversible, but still: using `std::size_t` where you originally intended to use `int` is a very strange idea (unless you that `int` was inappropriate in the first place).

Comment: Good point. In this scenario, the int was always used as a count for things, and using the original int constructor, there were numerous static casts from size_t to int or unsigned int to try to get around the compiler warning, so there is no concern about loss of data due to signage, as the value is never negative in this context. You are absolutely right, though, size_t does not act as a fool-proof replacement for int in all cases.